# Varnish redirecting to account page

Tags: magento2, varnish

I am having this problem with magento 2.x. Whenever I go to a product page, I get redirected to /customer/account. I have debugged it with firebug and I discovered this:

301 Moved Permanently (BFCache)

From what I understand it's varnish that's redirecting. However running bin/magento cache:clean/flush doesn't really help. Is there something I'm not seeing? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

(BFCache) means the redirect response is cached in your browser's cache, i.e. server did not sent you that 301 redirect actually.
Try to flush browser's cache first.